# CoGrouped Step wont filter other steps

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, saql

I have the following step built by co-grouping 2 datasets on their SIC codes so that the display shows the sum of Amount for each SIC Code Description. This works as I need it to.

```
    q1 = load "Opportunity"; 
    q2 = load "Industry_Mapping_Dataset"; 
    q2 = group q2 by ('SIC_Code', 'Sub_industry', 'Sic_Code_Description');
    q3 = cogroup q1 by 'SIC_CD', q2 by 'SIC_Code';
    q3 = foreach q3 generate q2.'Sub_industry' as 'Sub_industry', q2.'Sic_Code_Description' as 'Sic_Code_Description', sum(q1.'Amount') as 'sum_Amount';
    q3 = order q3 by ('Sub_industry' asc, 'sum_Amount' desc);
```

The problem I'm having is, the following selection bindings I have pulling data from this step comes out blank every time.

```
{{column(CoGroup_1.selection, ["Sic_Code_Description"]).asObject()}}
```

I was wondering, are you able to do a selection binding on a co-grouped step?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try changing your binding to:

{{column(CoGroup_1.result, ["Sic_Code_Description"]).asObject()}}

This will calculate the query and filter based on the result.